# jquery slideToggle() function within knockout template

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, slidetoggle, templating

So if I wanted to call a function with knockout's data-bind="click: ShowHide" how would i go about that?
keep in mind the data-bind is on an li element, which is being populated by a template. my function was as follows:

```
viewModel = {
LoadedReports: ko.observableArray([]),

ShowHide: function() {

            $(this).children().slideToggle('slow');
        }
}
```

and within my template I have :

```
<li data-bind="click: ShowHide, clickBubble: false"><'children elements being populated'></li>
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Got this one myself the other day. See the comment on Judah H.'s suggestion for what I had to do.

Answer (score 1):

Put the .ShowHide function on the object that represents the li (I'm assuming it's a LoadedReport instance.)

Put the .ShowHide on that. Alternately, you can put the .ShowHide function on your view model, then in your binding, use click: $root.ShowHide.

Comment: I actually figured this one out the other day. The reason actually lies in the $(this) selector. When an Li was being clicked on, it was passing the entire event to the function, so i needed this line instead:

$(e.currentTarget).siblings('ul').slideToggle();

thanks though!

Comment: Ok. You should post your answer here an accept it so that we know your question is answered, as it currently shows up in the unanswered questions query.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if anyone feels that this is already answered, but to me the answer wasn't clear. So here is a clear example:

```
<!-- Step 1 - Create the HTML File or the View -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Step 2 - Include jquery and knockout -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Step 3 - Add script to run when page loads -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            <!-- Step 4 - Create a ViewModel -->
            function viewModel() {
                _self = this;
                _self.showHide = function(viewModel, event) {
                    $(event.currentTarget).children('div').slideToggle();
                };
            };

            <!-- Step 5 -  Activates knockout.js bindings -->
          ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="">
    <div>
        Option 1
        <!-- Step 6 - Create a HTML Elements with bindings -->
        <div data-bind="click: showHide" style="border:2px solid;">
        Click me
            <div style="display: none;">
              Now you see me!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The difference from the question is simply that I am using `<div>` tags instead of `<li>` for this example.